# Is it possible to dynamically change view perspective on a 2d tile-map

Tags: javascript, react-native, html5-canvas, 2d

I am teaching myself React Native by building a board game app. I have built all of the logic and UI elements in RN already, but need to be able to display the game board and allow it to change with state. My idea was to build a tilemap with several layers to show the board game background, move spaces, game pieces, and an object layer I can interact with through JavaScript. I was also looking at game engines such as Phaser, but it seems overkill for this as the game and UI is built and just need to show gameboard change with game state. I think a Canvas implementation could work and that what I am pursuing now, also hoping doing a pure JavaScript will help me learn more before using game libraries.

The game is intended to be multi-player and am wondering about how to rotate the board to display the same information to other players from their perspective. I have only seen static views and scrolling map controls, not rotating.

Solutions I have come up with are building a separate tile map for each player and somehow linking their object layers; or some manual parsing through the map array to change what is at 0,0. Is there a simpler way to do this? Am I approaching this correctly?

Thanks for your time!